# How to put cursor between PS1 characters?

Tags: bash, ps1, readline

I'd like to put the insertion cursor of bash inside the PS1 variable:

`export PS1='\u@\h:<cursor here>:\w'`

Where the colons are included in the prompt (typing enter should result in a string "::").
Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @muru: I'd like to investigate how one could implement a lisp shell by automatically surrounding the cursor with () to make it more practical.

Comment: @UltimateHawk Forgive me if this is ignorant, but I've never used Lisp: What does that have to do with your question?